# how to output an attribute in a specified namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

Why does the following not work as I'd expect it to?

```
<root xmlns:ns0="xmlns" 
      ns0:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:ns1="xsi" 
      ns1:schemaLocation="[some schema location]" />
```

Basically, I'm trying to add schemaLocation to an xml file that doesn't have this by doing :-

```
<xsl:template match="/s:*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="some other namespace">
    <xsl:attribute namespace="xmlns" name="xsi">http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute namespace="xsi" name="schemaLocation">[some-loc]</xsl-attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

and Xalan-C gives the xml shown above.

What I'm trying to get is something like :-

```
<root xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      ns0:schemaLocation="[some schema location]" />
```

Comment: Might be a cut/paste problem, but where is the s-prefix used in your first match defined?

Comment: Apparently the XML sample you posted is your actual output. Can you also show your expected output (what you are trying to achieve)? Or somehow describe what "as I'd expect it to" is?

Comment: @conciliator Well the s-prefix is kinda irrelevant to the whole thing right? In any case, it's defined in the element <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:s="namespace1">

Comment: @LarsH Either I'd like to get the output I need or I'd like to be able to verify the xml document against the schema. If I run the first xml against a bunch of schema-validating DOM parsers, it simply doesn't do anything with the schemas.

Comment: I am a compiler. I break down at the first unknown I meet.

Comment: @owagh: Impossible for us to tell whether it's irrelevant. Since there is a problem, and we don't initially know the cause, we have little choice but to bark at everything that smells fishy.

Comment: True. But you did end up solving my problem anyways! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `<xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation">[some-loc]</xsl:attribute>`.

Edit (adding complete example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="some other namespace">
         <!--<xsl:attribute namespace="xmlns" name="xsi">http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance</xsl:attribute>-->
         <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation">[some-loc]</xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Depending on what exactly you're doing you can possibly use `<xsl:copy>` to copy the element instead of `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}"/>`; it's somewhat simpler.

Answer (score 3):

As I'm interpreting your question and inferring what you actually wanted, the problem is that you are putting a value in `namespace="..."` that you intend to be a namespace *prefix*, but is [actually supposed to be](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#creating-attributes) a *namespace URI*.

Thus the code you probably want is just one `<xsl:attribute>` element:

```
<xsl:template match="/s:*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="some other namespace">
    <xsl:attribute namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        name="xsi:schemaLocation">[some-loc]</xsl-attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Then the XSLT processor will output the specified `schemaLocation` attribute in the right namespace, and will also emit a namespace declaration for its prefix where needed (and its prefix may be `xsi:`, but doesn't have to be).

Part of the problem here is that people throw around the word "namespace" (mentally or to others) without being clear about what they mean. A namespace is not a namespace prefix, nor is it really a namespace URI. A namespace is *globally identified by* its URI, and *locally identified by* its prefix.

If the XSLT spec had named this attribute `namespace-uri="..."` instead of `namespace="..."`, fewer people would fall into this trap. You can also protect yourself by asking whether someone who says "namespace" really means "namespace URI", "namespace prefix", "namespace declaration", etc. etc.